Network Socket Address format used in Cisco ASA syslogs
I'm getting syslog logs from CISCO ASA where the ip addresses are coming in what I would call a non-standard format: The IP with port is being logged as 'd.d.d.d/port' (e.g. 10.0.1.2/63313') so it looks more like a url/CIDR address instead of the more  usual d.d.d.d:port.
Two questions really,

Is there a formal standard for this naming, as I couldn't find much (e.g.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) as I'm just intersted to know this.
Is there a way to change the output format of ASA syslogs to use a more normal format because our log parsers are picking these up as URLs not IP:port.



No, there is not.


Because there is no standard, there is no "normal" format.  You're probably better off changing your log parser.

Cheers. I was hoping there was a way to change ASA as in this format there is a risk of mixing up ip address with url depending on the regex I use I course.
